# JavaScript function: Not passing test case

Tags: javascript, function

I am writing a project. The basis of the project is finishing a web app that takes an input and searches an array for the search value.

The helper.js was provided:

```
// Flatten object keys into an array so that we search the entire object by the input value
const flattenObjectValuesIntoArray = (arrOfObjs) => {
  let flattenedObj;
  const flattenedObjsArr = [];
  for (let obj = 0; obj < arrOfObjs.length; obj++) {
    const objValues = Object.values(arrOfObjs[obj]);
    flattenedObj = [...objValues.flat()]
    flattenedObjsArr.push(flattenedObj)
  }
  return flattenedObjsArr;
};

// Structure filtered books as HTML and return
const structureBookAsHtml = (book) => {
  const bookDiv = document.createElement("div");
  bookDiv.setAttribute('class', 'bookDiv');
  
  const bookTitle = document.createElement("h2");
  bookTitle.innerHTML = book.title;
  bookTitle.setAttribute('class', 'bookTitle');

  const bookAuthor = document.createElement("h3");
  bookAuthor.innerHTML = book.author;

  const bookTags = document.createElement("p");
  bookTags.innerHTML = book.tags.join(", ");

  bookDiv.append(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookTags);
  
  return bookDiv;
};

const renderBooksToDom = (elements) => {
  const bookListContainer = document.querySelector("#bookList");
  bookListContainer.innerHTML = "";

  bookListContainer.append(...elements);
};
```

And this is what I have completed:

```
// Click handler for search button
const captureSearchValue = () => {
    var searchValue = document.getElementById("search-bar").value;
    return searchValue;
};


// Filter books based on search input
const filterBooks = (searchString, listOfBooks) => {
    searchString = captureSearchValue();
    listOfBooks = books;
    let filteredList = [];
    for(let i=0; i<listOfBooks.length; i++) {
     let bookArr = flattenObjectValuesIntoArray(listOfBooks);
     if(bookArr[i].includes(searchString)) {
       filteredList.push(listOfBooks[i]);
     }
    }
    return filteredList;
  };

// Empty the book list container, iterate over list of filtered books, return list of books formatted as HTML using the function in `helper.js` 
const structureBooksAsHtml = (books) => {
    const bookElements = books.map((book) => structureBookAsHtml(book));
  return bookElements;
   
};

// Handler triggered when a user clickers the "Search" button. Chains previously defined functions together to filter books based on the search value, formats the books as HTML and renders them to the DOM
const searchBtnClickHandler = (books) => {
    const searchValue = captureSearchValue();
    const filteredBooks = filterBooks(searchValue, books);
    const structuredBooks = structureBooksAsHtml(filteredBooks);
    renderBooksToDom(structuredBooks);    
};

// Grab search button from the DOM
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("search-btn");

// Attach an event listener to the search button
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { searchBtnClickHandler(books) });
```

Where I am getting stuck is that when I run the code in the course IDE I get this message. However, when I test the filterBooks function it DOES return an array with 2 objects?

Given the filter `fantasy`, your `filterBooks` function returned an array with `0` elements. We expected it to return `2`.

This is what was provided for the HTML and Book array:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="bookList.js"></script>
    <script src="bookList.test.js"></script>
    <script src="helper.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Book Finder</h1>
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search for books by tags">
    <button class="btn" id="search-btn">Search</button>
    <div id="bookList">
      <!-- List of books will be rendered here -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const books = [
  {
    title: "The City We Became",
    author: "N. K. Jemisin",
    tags: ["fantasy", "fiction", "afrofutursim", "science fiction", "sci-fi"]
  },
  {
    title: "The Catcher in the Rye",
    author: "J. D. Salinger",
    tags: ["fiction", "young adult", "YA", "realism", "coming of age", "classic"]
  },
  {
    title: "The Hundred Thousand Kingdoms",
    author: "N. K. Jemisin",
    tags: ["fantasy", "fiction", "adventure", "series"]
  },
  {
    title: "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind",
    author: "Yuval Noah Harari",
    tags: ["nonfiction", "history", "anthropology", "science", "sociology"]
  },
  {
    title: "Behave: The Biology of Humans at Our Best and Worst",
    author: "Robert M. Sapolsky",
    tags: ["nonfiction", "anthropology", "science", "sociology", "biology"]
  },
  {
    title: "The Parable of the Talents",
    author: "Octavia Butler", 
    tags: ["fiction", "dystopian", "science fiction"]
  },
  {
    title: "1984",
    author: "George Orwell", 
    tags: ["fiction", "dystopian", "science fiction", "classics", "adult"]
  },
  {
    title: "Remarkably Bright Creatures",
    author: "Shelby Van Pelt",
    tags: ["fiction", "mystery", "magical realism"]
  },
  {
    title: "Crying in H Mart",
    author: "Michelle Zauner",
    tags: ["memoir", "nonfiction", "autobiography"]
  },
  {
    title: "Wild: From Lost to Found on the Pacific Crest Trail",
    author: "Cheryl Strayed",
    tags: ["nonfiction", "memoir", "adventure", "travel"]
  }
]
```

Comment: You're calling `searchButtonClickHandler()` with an argument `books`. But the function doesn't have a parameter. Conversely, `filterBooks()` has 2 parameters, but you're calling it with no arguments.

Comment: Why not make it an executable snippet so people can run it?

Comment: Does that worked with linked documents in the HTML