# Why is the Book Finder project not returning results?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

Below "JavaScript" are the functions I wrote

The helper functions, book list and the HTML were provided for me.

When I click the Search Button it should render the book list to the page. Currently nothing is happening and I am not sure why.

Additionally, If anyone could provide reccomendations on how to test the code, I am getting errors reffering to ".document not defined".

JavaScript

```js
// Click handler for search button
const captureSearchValue = () => {
    var searchValue = document.getElementById("search-bar").value;
    return searchValue;
};


// Filter books based on search input
const filterBooks = (searchValue, books) => {
    const flattenedValues = flattenObjectValuesIntoArray(books);
    return flattenedValues.filter((book) => book.includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()));
};

// Empty the book list container, iterate over list of filtered books, return list of books formatted as HTML using the function in `helper.js` 
const structureBooksAsHtml = (books) => {
    const bookElements = books.map((book) => structureBookAsHtml(book));
  return bookElements;
   
};

// Handler triggered when a user clickers the "Search" button. Chains previously defined functions together to filter books based on the search value, formats the books as HTML and renders them to the DOM
const searchBtnClickHandler = () => {
    const searchValue = captureSearchValue();
    const filteredBooks = filterBooks(searchValue, books);
    const structuredBooks = structureBooksAsHtml(filteredBooks);
    renderBooksToDom(structuredBooks);    
};

// Grab search button from the DOM
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("search-btn");

// Attach an event listener to the search button
searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { searchBtnClickHandler(books) });
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="bookList.js"></script>
    <script src="bookList.test.js"></script>
    <script src="helper.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Book Finder</h1>
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search for books by tags">
    <button class="btn" id="search-btn">Search</button>
    <div id="bookList">
      <!-- List of books will be rendered here -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Book List

```js
const books = [
    {
      title: "The City We Became",
      author: "N. K. Jemisin",
      tags: ["fantasy", "fiction", "afrofutursim", "science fiction", "sci-fi"]
    },
    {
      title: "The Catcher in the Rye",
      author: "J. D. Salinger",
      tags: ["fiction", "young adult", "YA", "realism", "coming of age", "classic"]
    },
    {
      title: "The Hundred Thousand Kingdoms",
      author: "N. K. Jemisin",
      tags: ["fantasy", "fiction", "adventure", "series"]
    },
    {
      title: "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind",
      author: "Yuval Noah Harari",
      tags: ["nonfiction", "history", "anthropology", "science", "sociology"]
    },
    {
      title: "Behave: The Biology of Humans at Our Best and Worst",
      author: "Robert M. Sapolsky",
      tags: ["nonfiction", "anthropology", "science", "sociology", "biology"]
    },
    {
      title: "The Parable of the Talents",
      author: "Octavia Butler", 
      tags: ["fiction", "dystopian", "science fiction"]
    },
    {
      title: "1984",
      author: "George Orwell", 
      tags: ["fiction", "dystopian", "science fiction", "classics", "adult"]
    },
    {
      title: "Remarkably Bright Creatures",
      author: "Shelby Van Pelt",
      tags: ["fiction", "mystery", "magical realism"]
    },
    {
      title: "Crying in H Mart",
      author: "Michelle Zauner",
      tags: ["memoir", "nonfiction", "autobiography"]
    },
    {
      title: "Wild: From Lost to Found on the Pacific Crest Trail",
      author: "Cheryl Strayed",
      tags: ["nonfiction", "memoir", "adventure", "travel"]
    }
  ]
```

Helper Functions

```js
// Flatten object keys into an array so that we search the entire object by the input value
const flattenObjectValuesIntoArray = (arrOfObjs) => {
    let flattenedObj;
    const flattenedObjsArr = [];
    for (let obj = 0; obj < arrOfObjs.length; obj++) {
      const objValues = Object.values(arrOfObjs[obj]);
      flattenedObj = [...objValues.flat()]
      flattenedObjsArr.push(flattenedObj)
    }
    return flattenedObjsArr;
  };
  
  // Structure filtered books as HTML and return
  const structureBookAsHtml = (book) => {
    const bookDiv = document.createElement("div");
    bookDiv.setAttribute('class', 'bookDiv');
    
    const bookTitle = document.createElement("h2");
    bookTitle.innerHTML = book.title;
    bookTitle.setAttribute('class', 'bookTitle');
  
    const bookAuthor = document.createElement("h3");
    bookAuthor.innerHTML = book.author;
  
    const bookTags = document.createElement("p");
    bookTags.innerHTML = book.tags.join(", ");
  
    bookDiv.append(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookTags);
    
    return bookDiv;
  };
  
  const renderBooksToDom = (elements) => {
    const bookListContainer = document.querySelector("#bookList");
    bookListContainer.innerHTML = "";
  
    bookListContainer.append(...elements);
  };
```

I belive the error in the application are from these functions

```js
// Empty the book list container, iterate over list of filtered books, return list of books formatted as HTML using the function in `helper.js` 
const structureBooksAsHtml = (books) => {
    const bookElements = books.map((book) => structureBookAsHtml(book));
  return bookElements;
   
};

// Handler triggered when a user clickers the "Search" button. Chains previously defined functions together to filter books based on the search value, formats the books as HTML and renders them to the DOM
const searchBtnClickHandler = () => {
    const searchValue = captureSearchValue();
    const filteredBooks = filterBooks(searchValue, books);
    const structuredBooks = structureBooksAsHtml(filteredBooks);
    renderBooksToDom(structuredBooks);    
};
```

When the search button is clicked it should return a list pf books based on the search input and then render it to the DOM. Currently nothing happens when the search button is clicked. I am not sure where the error is occuring.

Comment: You're passing an argument in your call: `searchBtnClickHandler(books)` but the function doesn't have a corresponding parameter.

Comment: This looks like the same code you posted over a month ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789708/javascript-function-expected-to-exist-error. I even pointed out the same error above.

Comment: Please [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77789708/edit) to add details instead of creating a new, duplicate question